# Bug with Zend_Date calculating subtraction two date

Tags: php, zend-framework, date, zend-date

I write this function:

```
public function calcDifferentDate($dateStart, $dateEnd = false, $output = Zend_Date::DAY)
{
    $dateEnd = $dateEnd ? $dateEnd : Zend_Date::now()->toString('YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateStartZD = new Zend_Date($dateStart, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateEndZD = new Zend_Date($dateEnd, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    return $dateEndZD->sub($dateStartZD)->toString($output);
}
```

If call this:

```
echo calcDifferentDate('2011-11-10');
```

and today is: '2011-11-14'
the output returned is `05` and not `04`
why? where am I doing wrong?

P.S. I use ZF 1.11.11 version

---

### I found the solution

this work right! :D

```
public function calcDaysDiffDate($dateStart, $dateEnd = '')
{
    $dateEnd = !empty($dateEnd) ? $dateEnd : Zend_Date::now()->toString('YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateStartZD = new Zend_Date($dateStart, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateEndZD = new Zend_Date($dateEnd, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateStartZD->sub($dateEndZD);
    return $dateStartZD->getTimestamp() / (60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Comment: I got `Fatal error: Call to a member function toString() on a non-object in ...` and `$dateEndZD->sub($dateStartZD)` is returning 345600.

Comment: what is this function supposed to do? I looked at it for 30s now and it doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: My function is used to calculate the difference in days between two dates, it is not clear? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution:

```
public function calcDaysDiffDate($dateStart, $dateEnd = '')
{
    $dateEnd = !empty($dateEnd) ? $dateEnd : Zend_Date::now()->toString('YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateStartZD = new Zend_Date($dateStart, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateEndZD = new Zend_Date($dateEnd, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateStartZD->sub($dateEndZD);
    return $dateStartZD->getTimestamp() / (60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try returning this instead:

```
$newDate = new Zend_Date($dateEndZD->sub($dateStartZD), 'YYYY-MM-dd');
return $newDate->get($output);
```

The calculations are incorrect, I will try to get to that later. But for now, you'll need your *logic* to be similar to that, because like I said in my comment, your method was resulting in a `fatal error` due to the fact that your date subtraction was returning an integer instead of a `Zend_Date` object from which to call `toString()`.

**Edit**

Sorry about my presumptuous, not well-thought-out previous answer. After more *careful* testing I believe I found your issue. The `sub()` function accepts an optional second param `$part` which is the part of the date will be returned from the resulting date subtraction. No need to call a `toString()` now even if you could.

So without further adieu, here it is with the fixed return statement:

```
public function calcDifferentDate($dateStart, $dateEnd = false, $output = Zend_Date::DAY)
{
    $dateEnd = $dateEnd ? $dateEnd : Zend_Date::now()->toString('YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateStartZD = new Zend_Date($dateStart, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    $dateEndZD = new Zend_Date($dateEnd, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
    return $dateEndZD->sub($dateStartZD, $output); // <-- fixed
}
```

**Second Edit**

After chatting with OP, it appears that my solution will not work for ZF 1.11.x due to the differences in the `Zend_Date::sub()` method.

Comment: -1 have you tried the code before posting?
with your method returns 5, not 4! :S

Comment: I kinda did but I'm half asleep. it's almost sunrise here and I haven't gone to sleep yet. sorry for my half answer. If you haven't found your solution by tomorrow I will definitely give this another try and this time I'll be working with full brain power.

Comment: Ok! Thanks anyway! Good night!

Comment: Ok nevermind, I couldn't leave it like that. I think I found the solution. Try it now.

Comment: Correction: I _know_ I found the solution. I tested that function out with about 5 different dates and they all worked.

Comment: sorry but your solution return a Zend_Date object and not number day! :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4971/discussion-between-jellybelly-and-mmmshuddup)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer for this question: [How to compare the date parts of two Zend_Date objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120688/how-to-compare-the-date-parts-of-two-zend-date-objects) recommends using `DateTime` instead of `Zend_Date` in the following way (I've modified the code a bit to suit your needs):

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2011-11-14');
$date2 = new DateTime('2011-11-10');
$diffDays = $date1->diff($date2)->days;
```

I've tried it and it seems to return the correct result. It could be a good alternative to `Zend_Date`, if you are not absolutely required to use it.

Hope that helps,

Comment: yours is a good workaround, but I am always curious as to why the solution with Zend_Date is not behaving as it should.

Comment: After a second viewing of your solution is not what I needed! Why not have your way with the sign of the difference. Your method returns the simple difference and not -1 or 1, which is my case! :S

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment... In your comment to your original question you said that the function "is used to calculate the difference in days between two dates", right?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, but when I `2011-11-10` and `2011-11-14` I must return to `-4` and not `4`!

Comment: I for different I mean subtraction!

Comment: Ok, I understand now. In that case, you could combine a call to diff with comparison operators, available for DateTime objects according to the documentation: http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php