# How to compare the date parts of two Zend_Date objects?

Tags: php, zend-framework, date, zend-date

I'd like to check if to `Zend_Date` datetimes are on the same day. How can I do that?

```
$date1 = new Zend_Date('2011-11-14 10:45:00');
$date2 = new Zend_Date('2011-11-14 19:15:00');
```

Comment: Same day as in, Monday, Tuesday etc... or the same date, excluding time? I any case, Zend has a compare method. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.basic.html, you can extract whatever format you want.

Comment: Sorry for the possible confusion, I mean the same date, excluding time, *not* the same day of week!

Comment: kind of what i figured from the example, just making sure. Also heres a list of constants you might need. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$date1 = new Zend_Date('2011-11-14 10:45:00');
$date2 = new Zend_Date('2011-11-14 19:15:00');
if ($date1->compareDay($date2) === 0) {
    echo 'same day';
}
```

Also see the chapter on [Comparing Dates with Zend Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.basic.html#zend.date.simple.functions.compare)

On a sidenote, I strongly encourage you to verify if you have the need for `Zend_Date`. Do not use it just because it is part of ZF. Most of what `Zend_Date` does can be achieved faster and more comfortably with native [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) as well:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2011-11-14 10:45:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2011-11-14 19:15:00');
if ($date1->diff($date2)->days === 0) {
    echo 'same day';
}
```

---

**EDIT after comments**
If you want to compare whether it's the same date just do

```
$date1->compareDate($date2)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (`compare()` and `equals()` can only -AFAIK- compare the day of the month, not the full date part). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I had to de-tag your answer as accepted, after noticing that it actually only compares the day, not the date (+ month + year). Same day next month returned true as well.

Comment: @Benjamin errrm, of course it does because you asked for the **same day**, not the **same date**. if you want the same date just do `$date1->compareDate($date2)`

Comment: My god, such an obvious method name, thanks for showing me the light! There was confusion about *day* vs *date* at the time I wrote my question, clarified in the comments. Your answer is back to Accepted ;-)