# How can I compare a date (day/month) in PHP

Tags: php, compare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare the date parts of two Zend_Date objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120688/how-to-compare-the-date-parts-of-two-zend-date-objects)

I've been trying to compare dates, but for some reason things don't seem to work as I want them to.
I'm trying to log to a database whenever someone logs into my site on a certain day.
I've used if `(date("j F") == "25 July")` followed by my code, but it doesn't seem to trigger.
I intend to get it to check for a lot of things, such as Friday 13, 17 March, etc (obviously I know I'll need to change the date() format for Friday 13).
The current check of 25 July is a copy from an echo of date(), so I know it's definitely not a typo. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working, and how to do it?
Cheers

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.highlystructured.com/comparing_dates_php.html)

Comment: Use `strtotime` function while comparing.

Comment: please use the search function before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to use a strtotime function. But I think it won't work until you specify year in the date.

Not sure about it though. But strtotime is a good option.